# Ajax render of Tomahawk t:tree2 only renders the first node and child nodes are not expanded

Tags: ajax, jsf, tree, rendering, tomahawk

I have a form with a `selectOneMenu` and when I select the third "Visualizar todos los archivos" I want to render a `<t:tree2>`. All this is using Ajax to render the component when the value changes in the `selectOneMenu`.

What's happening is that only gets rendered the very first node of the tree, and when I click on the `+` sign next to the folder it does not expand at all.

This is my code:

```
    <h:form id="menuForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <h:outputLabel for="option" value="Acciones disponibles: " />
        <h:selectOneMenu id="option"
                         value="#{uploadFile.option}">
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Seleccione una opción..." itemValue="null" />
            <f:selectItems value="#{uploadFile.options}" />
            <f:ajax render="@form" execute="@form" />
        </h:selectOneMenu>

        <h:panelGrid id="dataLoad" columns ="3" 
                     rendered="#{uploadFile.option == 'Cargar información completa.' || 
                                 uploadFile.option == 'Cargar solo información errónea.'}">
            <h:outputLabel for="upfile" value="Archivo: " />
            <t:inputFileUpload id="upfile" 
                               value="#{uploadFile.upFile}" />
            <h:panelGroup/>
            <h:panelGroup/>
            <h:commandButton value="Continuar"
                             onclick="return confirmation()"
                             action="#{uploadFile.upload}" />
        </h:panelGrid>

        <h:panelGrid id="listFiles" columns="3"
                     rendered="#{uploadFile.option == 'Visualizar todos los archivos.'}">
            <t:tree2 id="tree" value="#{listFiles.treeRoot}"
                     var="node" varNodeToggler="t" >
                <f:facet name="folder">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <f:facet name="expand">
                            <t:graphicImage value="images/folderOpen.png"
                                            rendered="#{t.nodeExpanded}}"
                                            border="0" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <f:facet name="collapse">
                            <t:graphicImage value="images/folderClose.png"
                                            rendere="#{t.nodeExpanded}}"
                                            border="0" />
                        </f:facet>
                        <h:outputText value="#{node.description}"
                                      styleClass="nodeFolder" />
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
                <f:facet name="file">
                    <h:panelGroup>
                        <h:commandLink action="#{listFiles.download(node.identifier)}">
                            <t:graphicImage value="images/file.png" border="0" />
                            <h:outputText value="#{node.description}" />
                        </h:commandLink>
                    </h:panelGroup>
                </f:facet>
            </t:tree2>
        </h:panelGrid>
    </h:form>
```

What am I missing?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the scope of the `uploadFile` bean? You've by the way typos in the `rendered` attribute of both `<t:graphicImage>`s.

Comment: UploadFile bean is ViewScoped. (Checking for typos).

Comment: Yes, it was indeed the typos that didn't make it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have typos in the code. Note the `rendered` attribute of the following components:

```
<t:graphicImage value="images/folderOpen.png"
                rendered="#{t.nodeExpanded}}"
                border="0" />

<t:graphicImage value="images/folderClose.png"
                rendere="#{t.nodeExpanded}}"
                border="0" />
```

It should have been:

```
<t:graphicImage value="images/folderOpen.png"
                rendered="#{t.nodeExpanded}"
                border="0" />

<t:graphicImage value="images/folderClose.png"
                rendered="#{t.nodeExpanded}"
                border="0" />
```